# Javascript timing events

Tags: javascript

I want to display the message "Hi how are you?" for 1 minute using [JavaScript][1].  After 1 minute, I'd like it to disappear.  Can you help me write the code to produce this?

Edit: I have tried this code:

following is the code that i trid...

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function timeMsg() 
{  
   var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);
} 
function alertMsg() 
{
    document.write("Hellow"); 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form> <input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds" onclick="timeMsg()"/> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: check for `setTimeout` method in javascript to help the cause.. when you post a question please explain the steps you've taken if possible along with some code that you have tried and avoid generic questions. Please refer the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before you post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    /* hide message logic */
}, 60000);
```

Comment: following is the code that i trid...                           <html>                                                              
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function timeMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);
}
function alertMsg()
{
document.write("Hellow");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds"
onclick="timeMsg()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Use the method setTimeout :

```
setTimeout(function() {
// hide your message
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I figured its not enough **jQuery** in those other answers, here is mine!

```
jQuery( window ).delay( 6e+4 ).show(function() {
    /* hide message logic */
});
```

---

<sup>I'm trolling of course, `.setTimeout` will do just fine</sup>